# Ignore Certain Cells on Excel Bar Chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to make a concise Excel Bar Chart. I have a data set which has 245 data points on a single row. I would like to make a bar chart of this row however I would like Excel to ignore the rows with very low values.

In order to achieve this conversion, I have written this formula to convert the small numbers in the data set to #N/A:

```
=IF(OR(D47<0.01;ISBLANK(D47));NA();D47)
```

This formula successfully converts any number in my dataset which is smaller than 0.01 to the cell value #N/A. However, when I plot my bar graph, I still see the empty cells on the X-axis and this makes the graph appear huge.

What I want from Excel is just to hide the `#N/A` valued cells in the graph so the graph would be much more readable. How do you think I can fix this problem? Thank you very much for your time in advance.

Here is what the current graph looks like:
[Hard to read chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuVDe.png)

To sum up, I would like to remove all the cells which are not visible on the graph so the x-axis will resize itself to make the bars with values thicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the rows with #N/A. This can quickly be done with a filter

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response! This worked perfectly when I transposed my data.